# Powershell script running ssh on remote Linux machine hangs

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, shell

I have a PS script that in some moment starts the following loop

```
foreach($wiersz in $zm1.ParamValue -split ";")
{
   cmd /c "ssh -tt -i k4 user@$($wiersz) < script.sh"
}
```

and it starts the ssh connection and executes the script.sh content on the remote machine. The problem is that after the last script.sh command the ssh connection remains active and the PS script doesn't continue. How can I terminate the cmd /c execution, after it completes with success, and continue the PS script?

tried to add a logout or exit at the end of the linux bash script, but it didn't helped.

The script.sh contains as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F" " -v OFS=$";" '/\.channel\..*-- START/ {print $1" "$2";"$6";tst1n"}' /opt/logs/server.log.$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday) | grep -vw 'priv.poller' > services_$(hostname).log
logout
```

Comment: Check if the SSH connection is terminated when your `script.sh` contains **only** `exit`. Make sure the file contains UNIX line endings. If this works in contrast to your original file, show the contents of `script.sh`. Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: What happens when you use a script that contains **only** `exit #` and nothing else?